# Batch script - Ignore hash when reading lines from a file

Tags: batch-file

I would like to set variables from name value pairs in a properties. The property file has # for comments

====sample input file=====

```
#This is a comment
### Another comment
appNames=HelloWorldApp
targetServer=serverABC

DEV.key1=value1
TEST.key2=value2
```

=========
 I have 2 issues

1)

```
C:\temp\dos>for /f "delims=" %i in (test.properties) do @set %i
Environment variable #This is a not defined
Environment variable ### Another not defined
```

Variables are set, but I would like comments to be ignored. I would like to do this with a single line of code, but get this instead.

```
for /f "delims=" %i in (test.properties) do @echo %i | find "#">nul || @set %i
find: unable to access "#": The system cannot find the file specified.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
Environment variable #This is a not defined
find: unable to access "#": The system cannot find the file specified.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
```

2)
I would like this properties file to be passed as an argument to a batch script.Contents of the test.bat file

```
set propFilePathAndName=%1
for /f "delims=" %i in (%propFilePathAndName%) do echo %i
```

output

```
C:\temp\dos>set propFilePathAndName=/temp/dos/test.properties
propFilePathAndNamei was unexpected at this time.
```

If I run the contents of this file one line at a time , it works. 
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

To ignore lines starting with a hash, you could use the `eol` parameter of the for loop.
`for /f "eol=# delims=" %i in (test.properties) do @set %i`

The second issue is to double the percent inside of a batch file.

```
set propFilePathAndName=%1
for /f "delims=" %%i in (%propFilePathAndName%) do echo %%i
```

This is caused by the parser, there are different rules for the command line and batch files.

cmd-line
`for %a in (xyz) do echo %a`

batch-file
`for %%a in (xyz) do echo %%a`