# Batch - Read lines of one file except the ones starting with #

Tags: batch-file, windows-8

I would like to read a file line by line, but I would also like to ignore lines starting with #.
I have tried to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6963210/4589608) but it does not work for me. I am under Windows 8.

**Batch file reading all the lines**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "Tokens=* Delims=" %%x in (aliases.txt) do (
    set aliases=!aliases! "%%x"
)
```

**aliases.txt**

```
line 1 to read
# comment to ignore
line 2  to read
```

Comment: the `eol` should work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eol character is the character that specifies the end of line comment character. Nothing on the line after this character will be read after it is. By default, it's `;`, but you can set it to whatever you want.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "eol=# Tokens=* Delims=" %%x in (aliases.txt) do (
     set aliases=!aliases! "%%x"
)
```

Comment: I do not understand but now this works. Could did I have an encoding problem ? I have juste used ASCII encoding and then this works...

Comment: I've never heard of an encoding problem breaking eol, but to be fair, eol is one of those things that I never had much use for. That said, I (perhaps mistakenly) am under the impression `eol` has to be the first thing in the quoted section of the `for` loop to work properly.

Comment: No. I have put it in the second posiition. I have another idea : maybe I had a hidden file with old version of my BATCH file (I had sometimes this problem with Python scripts).

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I can't believe that the `eol` does not work.As an alternative you can try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "Tokens=* Delims=" %%x in ('findstr /v /b "#" aliases.txt') do (
    set aliases=!aliases! "%%x"
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this other way to do things